# Voltage Problem

Tags: electrical, lights

I modified my car taillight with SMD light same as image,
I tried them after installed with 12v DC 1000mA adaptor and was working well, but with car battery not worked,
After that I found out The SMD needed 24v power,

Now I need to increase the voltage,
Please if any one help me...
TQ.

Comment: Generally speaking, resistors can only reduce the voltage across a part.

Comment: @duskwuff , what can I do now....?

Comment: If it works with 12V adaptor and not with a 12V car then you may not be using it in the car as you think you are.

Comment: Image? Can you provide link to SMD lighjt

Comment: Problem solved friend,

Comment: Car battery can Suport each 4SMD, Completely DONE.

Answer (score 3):

You can

- buy a 12VDC to 24VDC converter which is rated for the needed current
- modify the led unit to operate with 12 volts (fewer leds in series in one strip, double number of strips, new current limiting resistors needed)
- buy a new led unit for 12V

The last option is the best for maintaining the reliability of your vehicle. Nothing that's made by unexperienced hobbyists will be good enough for cars.